# Firebase TestLabs : Where I can see results of XCUITest

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have uploaded an XCTest package to Firebase TestLabs. I can see the results for the Unit Tests but for UI test cases I can't see any output. Neither in the Video nor the Test Cases tab.

Does anyone know where I can see the result of UI Test cases? Firebase documentation for iOS Testing says **Test Lab runs unit tests and UI tests**.

Comment: If you're having problems navigating the console or to report an error, I suggest reaching out to to Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: No, I don't have any issues navigating to the console. In the console, I can see list of selected devices and also see the unit test cases which are passed. But what about UI test cases where does the result of it goes?